# How to expand table, by matching table's column against a vector?

Tags: r

I apologize if this question is duplicated.

There is a table `prod_table` looks like

```
      key price
1 Printer   225
2  Tablet   570
3  Laptop  1120
```

And vector `vec`

```
[1] "Printer" "Laptop"  "Printer" "Tablet"  "Laptop"
```

What I want is, match `prod_table$key` with `vec` and expand this table.

I tried `prod_table[vec,]` but it did not work.

Desired output looks like

```
      key price
1 Printer   225
2  Laptop  1120
3 Printer   225
4  Tablet   570
5  Laptop  1120
```

Here is reproducible example.

```
prod_table <- data.frame(
  key = c("Printer", "Tablet", "Laptop"),
  price = c(225, 570, 1120)
)
vec <- c("Printer", "Laptop", "Printer", "Tablet", "Laptop")
```

Comment: you can put the vector in a data.frame and then do a left join: `dplyr::left_join(data.frame(key=vec), prod_table)`.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for quick comment. I didn't knew about this way. Have a nice day :D

Comment: You can also use `match`, i.e. `data.frame(vec, price = prod_table$price[match(vec, prod_table$key)])`

Comment: @Sotos Thank you for base `R` way! I was not familiar with `match`. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `match` the vector with key.

```
prod_table[match(vec, prod_table$key), ]
#         key price
# 1   Printer   225
# 3    Laptop  1120
# 1.1 Printer   225
# 2    Tablet   570
# 3.1  Laptop  1120
```

Comment: This is also help me to solve this problem. Thanks a lot. Have a nice day :))

Comment: @jay.sf Not sure why "only matches once" should be a problem? `sapply(vec, match, prod_table$key)` gives the same output as `match(vec, prod_table$key)`.

Comment: @marl1 Actually you're right, probably I confused that with another problem I had where it didn't work. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Park Please notice updated answer!

Comment: Thanks for checking @jay.sf . Upvoting your answer.